# What are the different possible values for __name__ in a Python script, and what do they mean?

Tags: python

Checking to see if `__name__ == '__main__'` is a common idiom to run some code when the file is being called directly, rather than through a module.

In the process of writing a custom command for Django's manage.py, I found myself needing to use `code.InteractiveConsole`, which gives the effect to the user of a standard python shell.  In some test code I was doing, I found that in the script I'm trying to execute, I get that `__name__` is `__console__`, which caused my code (dependent on `__main__`) to not run.

I'm fairly certain that I have some things in my original implementation to change, but it got me wondering as to what different things `__name__` could be.  I couldn't find any documentation on the possible values, nor what they mean, so that's how I ended up here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the [document](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#code.InteractiveInterpreter) of class code.InteractiveInterpreter([locals]):
The optional locals argument specifies the dictionary in which code will be executed; it defaults to a newly created dictionary with key `'__name__'` set to `'__console__'` and key `'__doc__'` set to `None`.
maybe u can turnning the locals argument, set `__name__` with `__main__`, or change the test clause from

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
to  
if __name__ in set(["__main__", "__console__"])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Probably don't need the set() or list, could use a single tuple of strings.

Comment: @GringoSuave agree,:)

Answer (score 6):

`__name__` is usually the module name, but it's changed to `'__main__'` when the module in question is executed directly instead of being imported by another one.

I understand that other values can only be set directly by the code you're running.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/reference/toplevel_components.html for additional information.  `__name__` IS the module name.  `__main__` is a special module.